# ng new my-app unexpected token =

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have installed the angular2 cli via npm, but when I try to create a new typescript angular app with the command 'ng new my-app' I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Users\nicholas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:15
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nicholas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

My NPM version is 4.1.2
My node version is 4.4.5 which from my understanding are acceptable versions for installing and using the angular-cli.

Please let me know if there is a fix to this, I have also tried uninstalling, cleaning npm cache and reinstalling but I keep getting the same issue.

Any and all help is very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to download `node` version 6.9 or higher.

Comment: Before anyone rushes off to ask for code, this looks like an error coming from *within* Angular2.  Perhaps you should also check the GitHub site for it to see if there are any open bugs?

Comment: @Kinduser how come the Angular CLI quickstart guide specifies that I need node version 4.x.x or higher?

Comment: @Makoto thank you, I will check for open bugs.

Comment: I had the same bug today `C:\Projects>ng new sjerd
C:\Users\sjerd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:15
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Comment: Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.7.1 (x64) and npm.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have installed [**@angular/cli**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli), you need `NodeJS` higher **6.9.7**, together with `NPM` **3** or higher.

If you have installed **[angular-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli)**, you need `NodeJS` higher than **4.4.x**, together with `NPM` **3** or higher.

For more see the links above and read the prerequisites.

Comment: This answer would be better if you referenced some authority. That way it could be updated if those version numbers change.

Comment: thank you for the answer, this is true. I did need NodeJS 6.9.7 or higher, however the tutorial for this specifically states that you only need NodeJS 4.x.x or higher, check here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html , so it is misleading and I would not have known unless by asking the question here.

Comment: @Kinduser you were definitely right, I just try to follow the instructions diligently, especially when I am following instructions from Google. Need to post the answer quicker ;) nonetheless Thank You!

Comment: why are there two cli's that can be installed?  What's the difference? Is a certain scenario call for a specific one?  
Isn't one a dependency in the project.json and one is a devdependency in the project.json ?

Comment: The reason for the separate dependencies is separating the 2 versions of Angular right now. Angular 2 is still in development and needs the @angular/cli dependency, while Angular 1 is still using the angular/cli.

Comment: Excellent Answer.

Answer (score 7):

As of 2017-06-03, using Angular-CLI 1.1.0, NodeJS 7.10.0, npm 5.0.2, Angular 4.1.3, TypeScript 2.3.4, I experienced the error of the Original Poster (OP) in Visual Studio 2017 during Task Runner Explorer, running the build task (ng build as defined in package.json).

I launched a PowerShell prompt, navigated to the directory where the package.json lives, and invoked ng build from the command line, and it experienced zero errors.

That immediately raised my suspicions that it was a PATH (within VS 2017) issue that was causing the error to appear in VS 2017's Task Runner output window.

Sure enough, under Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / Web Package Management / External Tools, I had to move the entry for $(PATH) up above $(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External and (in my case at least) below .\node_modules.bin.

Once I did all of the above, I was able to right-click on build (under the Custom tab) of Task Runner Explorer and this time it was successful.

Before anybody replies, keep in mind the following:

1. This is VERY SPECIFIC to Visual Studio 2017 in which an Angular 4.1.3 application is being developed to (hopefully) peacefully co-exist with ASP.Net Core 1.1.
2. I have TypeScript 2.3 globally installed and locally installed.
3. I have the very latest NodeJS and NPM editions (as of the time of writing this post at least).
4. The techniques I used that resolved this issue for me may not work for you.

Bottom line: it might be the order of where things are in your PATH that might be causing the error.

Comment: I had the exact same problem today, and this fixed it! Thanks! :)

Comment: Really appreciate the solution!  Splendid!

Comment: Perfect.... but how did you get dependent tasks to wait for the `ng build` to finish?

Answer (score 0):

solved as followes:

do

ashish@ashish-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for ashish: 
root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish# sudo npm cache clean -f
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish# sudo npm install -g n
/usr/local/bin/n -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
/usr/local/lib
└── n@2.1.8

root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish# sudo n stable

```
 install : node-v9.8.0
   mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/9.8.0
   fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.8.0/node-v9.8.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

################################################################## 100.0%

################################################################## 100.0%

installed : v9.8.0

root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish# 
root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish# sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/9.8.0/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish# sudo n latest

```
 install : node-v9.9.0
   mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/9.9.0
   fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.9.0/node-v9.9.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

################################################################## 100.0%

installed : v9.9.0

root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish# 
root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish# ng -v

```
_                      _                 ____ _     ___
```

/ \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ***| |   |* *|
  / △ \ | '* \ / *`| | | | |/ _` | '***|   | |   | |    | |
 /  **\| | | | (*| | |*| | | (*| | |      | |***| |**_ | |
/*/   __| |*|__, |__,*|*|__,*|*|       __**|_____|***|
               |***/

Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 9.9.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
...
root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish# node -v
v9.9.0
root@ashish-Inspiron-3521:/home/ashish#