# SyntaxError: Unexpected token angular-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, angular-cli

node version in use: `v5.7.0`.

Trying install/upgrade angular-cli to latest version to support: `angular-4`

Upgraded npm to latest version using powershell as recommended by node team.

npm version in use after upgrade is: `4.5.0`(latest)

Later tried to install angular-cli using: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

[image]

Except 2 warning at last, everything was installed successfully

[image]

But when i just type in `ng` or `ng help`: I get error as:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` which is pointing to fallbacks argument in constructor function like this:

[image]

Instead of upgrading just `npm`, should we update node version as specified in: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites?

Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running an outdated version of the node. You should have node 6.9.0 as per wiki

> Angular CLI can now be found on NPM under @angular/cli instead of
>   angular-cli, and has a minimum requirement of Node 6.9.0 or higher,
>   together with NPM 3 or higher.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

That could be related to the problem of updating angular.

I suggest using chocolatey package manager to update nodejs https://chocolatey.org/

Alternatively, you can always go to nodejs website and download latest version.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to upgrade to latest node version and it got resolved. But its all a workaround for me to re-install all global node modules

Comment: Well you can see what packages you have installed globally by running npm -g ls --depth=0 and then reinstall all the packages that came up.

Comment: According to a post made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166096/ng-new-my-app-unexpected-token) you can use `angular-cli` with node version `4.4.x` or higher. (note: angular-cli !== @angluar-cli)