# Installing @angular/cli from npm on Ubuntu Server

Tags: angular, ubuntu, angular-cli

I have an Ubuntu instance on AWS, I'm using forge to setup the server.
I have installed the packages nodejs and npm.
To solve the problem of installing global packages on Ubuntu I have followed the second solution mentioned in this tutorial,
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Now when I try to install using this command,

> npm install -g @angular/cli

I get the following error,

```
forge@frontend-staging:~/frontend/current$ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

▐ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine @angular/cli@1.1.0: wanted: {"node":">= 6.9.0","npm":">= 3.0.0"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
loadDep:node-sass → heade ▌ ╢███████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:node-sass → resol ▄ ╢███████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:node-sass → mapTo ▀ ╢███████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:node-sass → after ▐ ╢███████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:@ngtools/json-sch ▄ ╢████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
loadDep:yargs → 200       ▌ ╢█████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
/home/forge/.npm-global/bin/ng -> /home/forge/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> node-sass@4.5.3 install /home/forge/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN install:node-sass@4.5.3 node-sass@4.5.3 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN install:node-sass@4.5.3 spawn ENOENT
/home/forge/.npm-global/lib
└─┬ @angular/cli@1.1.0 
  └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY node-sass@^4.3.0

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@angular/cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.1

Comment: Clear all the relevant node_modules, cache, appdata and then reinstall nodejs. Login as a `sudo` user. use the command `sudo npm install ...`

Answer (score 0):

Run Following commands,

```
sudo apt-get uninstall nodejs

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Now, check your node/npm version using

```
node -v 
npm -v
```

Then try to install CLI.

Comment: `sudo apt-get uninstall nodejs` returns `E: Invalid operation uninstall`, correct command is I think, `sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

We can use yarn package manager. Its fast, easy, understandable (meaningful). You can :

1. Install yarn

   npm install yarn -g
2. use yarn to install angular-cli

`yarn global add angular-cli`

Done thats its it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this, the problem was caused by my version of node installer **4.7.2** and not newer **6.x** version [as per this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786272/why-does-installing-node-6-x-on-ubuntu-16-04-actually-install-node-4-2-6). So I installed **angular-cli** instead as [this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42166431/4476246).

> If you have installed [**@angular/cli**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli), you need `NodeJS` higher
>   **6.9.7**, together with `NPM` **3** or higher.
>
> If you have installed **[angular-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli)**, you need `NodeJS` higher
>    than **4.4.x**, together with `NPM` **3** or higher.
>
> For more see the links above and read the prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your configuration is "current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"}". As per the documentation, You need to have 
Node 6.9.0 or higher and NPM 3 or higher.
For more information, Please visit Official Site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli.

What you need to do is, Update your node version. All d best!!!